# File structure for Maven base selenium project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, ant

I have been using Ant (Normal Java Project) to run my Selenium (java) test cases using Eclipse IDE. But now I am using Maven project; I was told that it has better structure, however I don't understand what benefit I'll get with structure. 
When I was using Ant, I had to create packages, folders manually but now when I moved to Maven I've got all folders, packages created by Maven itself.
**How it looks:it is a `maven-archetype-quickstart` project**

[image]

**Queries:**
1. Is this the only reason I should be using Maven, that it creates folders and packages for me (I know that I dont have to create library folder to put essential jars; I can use Maven repo)?

2. What is the meaning of these created folders, How I should be using them ideally?

3. Does Maven provides the most optimum structure `maven-archetype-quickstart`?

*Note: I am a tester and I am pursuing Selenium Automation testing. Dont mind if this is not a nice question, I am a beginner.*

Comment: Take a look [here](http://khmarbaise.github.io/maui/) and in particular this [example for a container example with selenium](http://khmarbaise.github.io/maui/it-example-container.html) furthermore you can look at the [code examples](http://khmarbaise.github.io/maui/examples.html) and a [full working example with Selenium etc.](https://github.com/khmarbaise/maui/tree/master/src/main/resources/it-example-container-selenium)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.: Folders and packages, is not the only benefit. It also gives you a proper project structure. This is convention over configuration, since when you understood the structure of one Maven project, you won't get lost in any other project. I suggest to read a book about Maven, for instance "Better Builds with Maven".

2.: src/main/java: all your source classes, src/main/resource: addtional resources, src/test/java: test classes, src/test/resources: additional resources for the test

3.: The quickstart is good for a starter. It is true that it has a quite old JUnit dependency and creates some default folders and classes. But if you want a different type of project there a lot of other archetypes out there. If you use the command

`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=test -DartifactId=test`

you will get a long list of available archetypes to choose from.

If you use eclipse you can also select the archetype in a dialog.

There is a [archetype](https://github.com/sebarmeli/Selenium2-Java-QuickStart-Archetype) for Selenium projects, but it requires understanding of Maven and Git.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you're using a mighty old version of maven, since it has a default dependency on junit 3.8.1. (the newest one is 4.11)

Your selenium tests should go into the src/test/java in a package you name yourself. (for example com.company.project) That way maven knows it should treat those files as tests and you don't have to do any more configuration.

If you want to run your tests, you just enter the following command in your prompt/shell:

> mvn clean install

Maven will then fetch all your dependencies, compile all your code and then run your tests. If the tests succeed, your build is succesful. If they fail, your build will also fail.

The problem with the default maven eclipse archetypes in my opinion is that they are a bit too vague. In my opinion they are useful if you have a company wide structure of how you should start a project, but by default the standard one should suffice.